# Unity Coordinate Limitations and its impact

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Some objects which I have placed at a position **(-19026.65,58.29961, 1157)** from the origin (0,0,0) are rendering with issues, the problem is referred to as **spatial Jitter** (SJ) [ref](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.471.7201&rep=rep1&type=pdf). Like You can check its detail [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/157362/object-lit-shader-or-huge-distance-from-origin-problem-in-large-unity-project) or You can see the **below image**. The objects are rendering with black spots/lines or maybe it is Mesh flickering. (Actually, I can't describe the problem, maybe the picture will help you to understand it)

[image]

I have also tried to change the camera near and far clipping but it was useless. Why I am getting this? Maybe my object and camera are far away from the origin.

**Remember:**

I have a large environment and some of my game objects (where the problem is) are at **(-19026.65,58.29961, 1157)** position. And **I guess this is the problem that Object and Camera are very far from the origin (0,0,0)**. I found numerous discussions which is given below

1. [GIS Terrain and Unity](https://unity3d.com/learn/resources/talks/gis-terrain-unity)
2. [Unity Coordinates bound Question at unity](https://answers.unity.com/questions/25124/unity-3d-world-space-coordinate-bounds.html)
3. [Unity Coordinate and Scale - Post](http://davenewson.com/posts/2013/unity-coordinates-and-scales.html)
4. [Infinite Runner and Unity Coordinates](https://answers.unity.com/questions/710798/infinite-runner-and-coordinates-limit.html)

I didn't find that what is the minimum or maximum limit to place the Object in unity so that works correctly.

Comment: There is no baking in the scene.

Comment: Is this the problem you're seeing perhaps? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting

Comment: I guess this is not the z-fighting my objects are rendering with black lines or spot which is another issue . i guess

Answer (score 2):

Since the world origin is a vector 3(0,0,0), the max limit that you can place an object would be `3.402823 × 10^38` since it is a floating point. However, as you are finding, this does not necessarily mean that placing something here will insure it works properly. Your limitation will be bound by what other performance factors your have in your game. If you need to have items placed at this point in the world space,consider building objects at runtime based on where the camera is. This will allow the performance to work at different points from the origin.

Unity suggests: not recommended to go any further than 100,000 units away from the center, the editor will warn you. If you notice in today's gaming world, many games move the world around the player rather than the player around the world.

To quote Dave Newson's site [Read Here](http://davenewson.com/posts/2013/unity-coordinates-and-scales.html):

> **Floating Point Accuracy**
>
> Unity allows you to place objects anywhere
>   within the limitations of the float-based coordinate system. The
>   limitation for the X, Y and Z Position Transform is 7 significant
>   digits, with a decimal place anywhere within those 7 digits; in effect
>   you could place an object at 12345.67 or 12.34567, for just two
>   examples.
>
> With this system, the further away from the origin (0.000000 -
>   absolute zero) you get, the more floating-point precision you lose.
>   For example, accepting that one unit (1u) equals one meter (1m), an
>   object at 1.234567 has a floating point accuracy to 6 decimal places
>   (a micrometer), while an object at 76543.21 can only have two decimal
>   places (a centimeter), and is thus less accurate.
>
> The degradation of accuracy as you get further away from the origin
>   becomes an obvious problem when you want to work at a small scale. If
>   you wanted to move an object positioned at 765432.1 by 0.01 (one
>   centimeter), you wouldn't be able to as that level of accuracy doesn't
>   exist that far away from the origin.
>
> This may not seem like a huge problem, but this issue of losing
>   floating point accuracy at greater distances is the reason you start
>   to see things like camera jitter and inaccurate physics when you stray
>   too far from the origin. Most games try to keep things reasonably
>   close to the origin to avoid these problems.

Comment: So why i am getting this problem?

Comment: @MuhammadFaizanKhan You can read all about it here: http://davenewson.com/posts/2013/unity-coordinates-and-scales.html  He actually suggests using multiple cameras

Comment: Yeah i have read  it already and i mentioned its reference in my question.

Comment: But how it is effecting rendering performance. I don't have any position problem all the objects are working fine but its rendering is not good. Additionally, the object is not much far away from the distance  (-19026.65,58.29961, 1157). As you said in the answer that unity generate warning when exceeding 1000,000 but in my case i am under -20000.